# Return Entity when using inner join and group by with NHIbernate (C#)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, group-by, entity, inner-join

I'm forced to use NHibernate for this project, and I'm just trying to run a pretty simple query.

I have two tables: Contacts and ContactHistories.  I want to return Contact entities that have at least one record in ContactHistories.....pretty simple.

In SQL, I'd just do

```
select c.ContactId
from Contacts c
inner join ContactHistories ch on ch.ContactId = c.ContactId
group by c.ContactId
```

to return a list of IDs for these contacts.

How would I go about returning the entities in NHibernate?

So far I've tried:

```
ICriteria criteria = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (Contact))
            .CreateAlias("ContactHistories", "ch", JoinType.InnerJoin)
            .SetProjection(Projections.GroupProperty("Id"))
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("ch.Partner", partner))
            .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity);
        return criteria.List<Contact>();
```

But, this just seems to return a list of IDs instead of a list of Contact entities.  I get:

> The value "3" is not of type "MyCompany.MyNamespace.Contact".

I'm even open to solutions that use Session.CreateQuery or Session.CreateSQLQuery.

For the record, Entity Framework is awesome.

Comment: Do you have association between Contacts and ContactHistories in nhibernate mapping? Or these tables are not related in mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `Contact` and `ContactHistory` tables are connected in mapping, and `Contact` class have a collection of child `ContactHistory`, you can use this HQL query to retrieve all contacts which have al least one history record:

```
var contacts = 
  s.CreateQuery("from Contacts c where size(c.ContactHistories) > 0")
  .List<Contact>();
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now all my Contact objects have a ContactHistories property that I can enumerate.  I had to make the map say:
    HasMany(x => x.ContactHistories)
                    .KeyColumn("ContactId")
                    .AsBag();